# MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client starts and stops immediately

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have started this SQL Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HXV3zeQKqGY&t=3466s and I installed MySQL and when I try to launch MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client it starts and stops immediately. I want to specify that during the instalation it never asked me to set a root password for the database like it asks the person in the video.

Comment: How do you run it? `>mysql -uroot -p` for example

Comment: I open the application by the icon.

Comment: To run the command line client. First you must first open a command windows to give you access to a command line

Comment: Please explain by steps in dummy terms.

Comment: Windows or Linux

Comment: I am using windows

Comment: I'm a noob when it comes to using the command prompt but I will assume that i would have to type "cd C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld" right? But after typing this it says " the directory name is invalid"

Comment: I have gone to the file location and opened mysqld and it's just a blank command prompt

Comment: `mysqld` is the MySQL Server. I think RiggsFolly gave you a misleading documentation link. The client is simply called [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql.html).

Comment: Woops so I did, sorry

Answer (score 0):

For whoever has this problem, just open your mysql-installer-web-community-8.0.22.0.msi without uninstalling and press reconfigure next to MySQL Server. Now it gave me the option to set a root password and the client starts normally